# Ruby PG gem use array as param with exec_params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, postgresql, pg

I want to pass a ruby array value like so:

```
sql = "SELECT $1"
User.connection.raw_connection.exec_params(sql, [[1,2]])
```

This returns

```
PG::IndeterminateDatatype: ERROR:  could not determine data type of parameter $1
```

If I change `sql` to `"SELECT $1::int[]"` I get `PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "[1, 2]"`.

Is there a way to pass a ruby array into `exec_params` and have it transformed into a PostgreSQL array?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the encoders to do that:

```
raw_connection.exec(
  "select $1::int[]",
  [PG::TextEncoder::Array.new.encode([1, 2])]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it as below :

```
params = [1, 2]
sql = params.size.times.map { |n| "$#{n+1}::INT" }.join(",")
User.connection.raw_connection.exec_params("SELECT #{sql}", params)
```

Answer (score 0):

[pg_exec_array_params](https://github.com/lunatic-cat/pg_exec_array_params) gem allows this:

```rb
# Instead of:
# PG::Connection.exec_params(
#   'SELECT ARRAY[$1, $2]'
#   [1, 2]
# )
PgExecArrayParams.exec_array_params(conn, 'select $1', [[1, 2]])
=> [{"array"=>"{1,2}"}]
```